# .htacces redirect with wildcard match

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm moving an old site to a new platform and the query strings have changed so looking to 301 them but no luck yet... so an old search string by state for example I'm using:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^a=19&b[yes_state]=(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^c/system\.php$ https://thenewwebsite.com/?cp_search=1&spost_region=%1 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

to basically send:
`theoldwebsite.com/c/system.php?a=19&b[yes_state]=Texas`
to
`thenewwebsite.com/?search=1&t_region=Texas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regular expression  **[** and **]** are [special characters](http://regular-expressions.mobi/charclass.html) ,you need to escape them by using a backslash in front  to match them litterlly.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^a=19&b\[yes_state\]=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^c/system\.php$ https://thenewwebsite.com/?cp_search=1&spost_region=%1 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi, other indexed strings seem to look like this %5Byes_state%5D= for the  [ and ] special characters, do we need another directive for this format?